# Can't login on localhost for one app, but can login for the other app (on similar subdomain). Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I have one app on name.mydomain.com and the other on name2.mydomain.com. Since yesterday I can’t login to a localhost on name.mydomain.com. Backend is started, frontend is redirected to a localhost, registration page is there, BUT credentials are not accepted and there is no error. I can login as a user.

When login to a second app name2.mydomain.com, I can login on a localhost registration page and pass. I can login as a user too.

What's the cause for failed localhost registration to the first app?

This is the code in authorization.js file for app2, which works for localhost and user:

```
import {hashHistory} from './hashHistory';
import {resetLoadedLabsState} from './labData';

const API_SERVER = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('accessTokenCompanies');
    
    resetLoadedLabsState();
    hashHistory.push('/');
    window.location.reload();
};

export const force_logout= () => 
{
    localStorage.removeItem('accessTokenCompanies');
    localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
    resetLoadedLabsState();
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//"+ window.location.host;
    
    return null;
}
export const unauthorizedHandler = res => {
   
    if (res.status === 401) {
        force_logout();
    }

    return res;
};

export const planNotSuitableHandler = async res => {
    if (res.status === 402) {
        const data = await res.json();
        alert(data.message || 'Your plan is not suitable for this action. Please contact support to upgrade!');
        throw new Error('plan not suitable');
    }

    return res;
};

export const storeAccessToken = token => {
    localStorage.setItem('accessTokenCompanies', token);
};

export const apiHeadersWithAuthorization = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessTokenCompanies');

    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    };
};

export const isLoggedIn = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessTokenCompanies');
    return !!token;
};

export const loadCurrentUser = async setCurrentUser => {
    const currentUser = await fetch(`${API_SERVER}/me`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: apiHeadersWithAuthorization(),
    }).then(unauthorizedHandler).then(res => res.json()).catch(console.error);

    setCurrentUser(currentUser || {});
};
```

This is the code for app1 that works for user but not localhost:

```
import {hashHistory} from './hashHistory';
import {resetLoadedLabsState} from './labData';

const API_SERVER = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    resetLoadedLabsState();
    hashHistory.push('/');
    window.location.reload();
};

export const force_logout= () => 
{
    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
    resetLoadedLabsState();
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//"+ window.location.host;

    return null;
}

export const unauthorizedHandler = res => {
    if (res.status === 401) {
        logout();
        throw new Error('unauthorized');
    }

    return res;
};

export const planNotSuitableHandler = async res => {
    if (res.status === 402) {
        const data = await res.json();
        alert(data.message || 'Your plan is not suitable for this action. Please contact support to upgrade!');
        throw new Error('plan not suitable');
    }

    return res;
};

export const storeAccessToken = token => {
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
};

export const apiHeadersWithAuthorization = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'X-xxx-App-Version': process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION,
    };
};

export const isLoggedIn = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    return !!token;
};

export const loadCurrentUser = async setCurrentUser => {
    const currentUser = await fetch(`${API_SERVER}/me`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: apiHeadersWithAuthorization(),
    }).then(unauthorizedHandler).then(res => res.json()).catch(console.error);

    setCurrentUser(currentUser || {});
};
```

Comment: Could this have anything to do with how you handle sessions?

Comment: If this happens to me I generally had done something with my database and didn't adjust my code properly. Where it may not matter for logging in, registering I would insert a new row into accounts and if it had missing fields it will throw errors. If this sounds like that go see what your database is reporting back for an error when you send the request. There's no real clear answer, every setup varies greatly.

Comment: Maybe some key has expired ? Is there something in e.g. the localStorage ?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Re: handle sessions
I don’t think so, both apps are started in a same manner, I had the access to both and could modify the frontend, but since recently can’t login in localhost to just one. But even if I can’t login to it in a localhost, still when do changes I can push them and they appear in a production in the user's side.

Of course, I don’t want to push anything without seeing how it looks in a localhost first. So weird...

If empty credentials, I get automated message insert a valid email or key. But when I enter any random staff, it doesn’t throw such user doesn’t exist

Comment: @kca
 which key can be there?

Comment: whatever keys or tokens you are using. like "access-token", "API key", "access-key", just "token", "bearer", ...

Comment: @kca but why it should be different for localhost vs user? If the backend for both apps is the same. So you say it can be a different key/token for localhost and user? Where to search for it? In a backend code or in MongoDB?

Comment: I don't know which keys / tokens you use. It was just an idea that maybe some expired key is stored in the browser storage (or somewhere else), for that user / that domain, but the problem is probably something else anyway.

Comment: Okay so when switching from development/production your domain name will be different for the session try running it no name, so it links to the IP requesting it. You can change this in production. If you go into developer console on your favorite browser and check network tab and the website request you should see if a cookie is associated with the request should reveal a lot of intel.

Comment: Above to summarize, if your set the cookie for *.example.com; the client visiting 127.0.0.1 will not offer the cookie for *.example.com, instead a cookie for 127.0.0.1.